# What does "migration" mean in Programming?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I'm learning Ruby on Rails and it talk about how Migration changes the state of the database by using the command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`, but what exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 8):

Migrations are a way of defining the schema of your database. Rails provides an API for adding/dropping/modifying database columns and tables using Ruby code. These files are knows as migrations. Here is a link to the documentation: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html,
but migrations are not a concept unique to Rails. For example, Django also uses migrations to manage the state of the database. The short answer is that migrations are a code-based way to manage the structure, or schema of your database.

Answer (score 0):

It executes all the migrations that you created/generated via rails generate migration X.

Basically migrations are scripts that deal directly with the database (creating tables, fields, indexes). Hope that helps! :)

Comment: So when I use the command "bundle exec rake db:migrate", it's creating migrations to manage and create tables, etc to the database?

Comment: It actually runs the migrations you've created via either creating rails models (rails g model Name) or migrations (rails g migration Name)